# Generating samples for any distribution

Tags: python, numpy, probability, sampling

I want to generate `1000` samples from a distribution in python:

`p(x1, ..., xn) = p(x1)p(x2|x1)(x3|x2)...p(xn|xn-1)` where `xn` can take `0`or `1`

where `p(x1=1) = 0.75`, `p(x_n = 1|x_n-1 = 1)=0.75` and `p(x_n = 0|x_n-1 = 0)=0.75`
and then count the number of samples out of the 1000 samples that has `x2=1`, so as to get rough approximation of the `p(x2=1)`

Had it been a `normal distribution`, I would have used `numpy.random.normal(mean, covariance, no of samples)`

How do I implement it?

Comment: This seems simple enough; if you can generate {0,1} with {0.75,0.25} probability, then the rest is just logic.

Comment: Are you really looking for p(x2=1), or did you mean to say p(xn=1)? Be that as it may, this is a discrete time, discrete state Markov chain, and the transition probabilities are the same at every step, so the transition matrix p(xk | xj) for any j < k is just A^^(k - j) where A is the transition matrix and A^^m is the m-fold product A . A . A ... A (m times). Be careful, that's not each element raised to the power m. You can get the marginal p(xk = 1) by multiplying A^^(k - 1) . p(x1).